Analytical function from summation representing Dollar Cost Averaging
I would like to understand what is the math necessary to go from a summation representing the Dollar Cost Averaging (DCA) to the analytical function.
In DCA, a certain capital $C_0$ is invested periodically. Let's assume a constant return $i$ relative to the same period (e.g. annual investment and annual return). The value of the invested capital after $N$ periods, $C(N)$, is therefore:
$$C(N) = C_0\sum_{n=1}^{N}\big(i+1\big)^n$$
I was trying to obtain the "analytical solution", i.e. a continuous function $f_{DCA}(t)$ (with $t$ real) such that
$$f_{DCA}(N) \equiv C(N) \quad \forall N\in\mathbb{N} $$
It does not need to reproduce the real capital at each time, since that would be discontinuous, because there is a "jump" of $C_0$ at each period. I just want the simplest function that follows $C(N)$.
I'm not good with summations, so I was playing with Desmos trying to find that function. After a long time I found that
$$f_{DCA}(t) = C_0\dfrac{(i+1)}{i}\Big(\big(i+1\big)^{t}-1\Big)$$
is exactly what I was looking for. However, it is impossible for me to understand how to go from $C(N)$ to $f_{DCA}(t)$. Is there a math trick that can explain it?

We have
$$C_N= C_0\sum_{n=1}^{N}\big(i+1\big)^n \quad (1)$$
Dividing both sides by $(1+i)$
$$\frac{C_N}{1+i}= C_0\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\big(i+1\big)^n \quad (2)$$
Subtracting (2) from (1) gives
$$C_N\cdot \left(1- \frac{1}{1+i}\right)=C_0\cdot \left((1+i)^N-(1+i)^0\right)  $$
$$C_N\cdot \frac{i}{1+i}=C_0\cdot \left((1+i)^N-1\right)  $$
I think you can do the rest. Finally replace $N$ by $t$.
